# Como obtengo acceso para instalar modulos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, cmd, vscode

Quiero instalar un modulo de node globalmente en windows y me pasa lo siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego me aparece esto en el vsCode:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ejecuta cmd como administrador

Comment: Aun así no me deja